# Woocommerce shortcode needed for Forgot Password

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, passwords, shortcode, forgot-password

Can someone help me out with Woocommerce issue. I see that they removed shortcode for forgot password, but I am in need of one, since I am trying to embed the form in pop-up.

If anyone who had a similar problem can help, it would be great.

In the end, it doesnt need to be a Woocommerce one, it can be anything.

Answer (score 8):

Below custom shortcode that allow you use `[lost_password_form]` shortcode

```
<?php 

function wc_custom_lost_password_form( $atts ) {

    return wc_get_template( 'myaccount/form-lost-password.php', array( 'form' => 'lost_password' ) );

}
add_shortcode( 'lost_password_form', 'wc_custom_lost_password_form' );

?>
```